# AJAX request script not working executing database query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, postgresql

I'm making a simple code to perfom an AJAX request that makes a database query and the return the data. The problem is that pg_query() is returning me false. The php documentation says:

> If an error occurs , and FALSE is returned , you can recover the details of this error with pg_last_error () function if the connection is valid .

I tried with the pg_last_error() but is not returning me anything, so obviusly the conection is not valid, but when I include the database conection class It gives me a 500 internal server error and I think if because I opened that same conection in the php file that is making the AJAX request. Any idea how can I resolve this?

**The php script:**

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['idCliente'])){
        $id_cliente = $_POST['idCliente'];
        /* Consulta para obtener todos los proyectos de un cliente con id 'id_cliente' */
        $proyectos = "SELECT * FROM serviciocliente WHERE codcliente = ". $id_cliente ." ORDER BY nombreserservicio";
        $result_proyectos = pg_query($proyectos);
        echo pg_last_error();
        print_r($result_proyectos);
        echo json_encode($result_proyectos);
    }
?>
```

**the jquery script:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#cliente').on('change', function() {
    var idCliente = this.value;
    $('#proyectos').empty();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getClientes.php",
      data: { 'idCliente': idCliente  },
      success: function(data){
        // Parse the returned json data
        var opts = $.parseJSON(data);
        // Use jQuery's each to iterate over the opts value
        $.each(opts, function(i, d) {
          $('#proyectos').append('<option value="' + d.ID + '">' + d.Name + '</option>');
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your script is open to SQL injection attacks. Solving them will solve your unquoted string problem. You can solve all of this with PDO prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: Check your php and server logs to get more information about what is causing the 500 error.  If I had to venture a guess I would say it's a configuration issue